# What is physical meaning of $\kappa$ and $R$ in curved space?

Tags: differential-geometry

What is physical meaning of $\kappa$ and $R$ in curved space?

$$dl^2 = \frac{dr^2}{1 - \kappa\frac{r^2}{R^2}}
+ r^2d\theta^2 + r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2$$

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but relevant and I found it useful: In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.2788) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0704.3265) paper, the author discusses the reasonable coordinate systems for some spacetimes of physical interest. Specifically, check page 21 and 10 respectively.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Reduced-circumference_polar_coordinates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a metric for a space of constant curvature in 3 dimensions.  Typically you would parameterise $\kappa$ as -1, 0, or 1 and $R$ as a non zero real number.  So $\kappa$ just tells you if you have positive, negative or no curvature and $R$ tells you the magnitude of the curvature.  $R$ can be thought of as a radius of curvature if you choose to embed your 3-space in a higher dimensional space.

For example, if you take $\kappa=1$ and subsitute $$r=R \sin\psi$$ you'll get a 3 sphere metric (in spherical polars) with an $R^2$ overall factor.